# Self closing tag space issue in xml - Cheerio

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, tags, cheerio

My issue is not preserving the space in the XML close tag during the cheerio parse.

```
const xmlstr = <plugin> <testId /> <classId /> <goalsone> <goals /> <info>new</info> </goalsone> </plugin>;

const $one = cheerio.load(xmlstr, { xmlMode: true });

console.log( $one.xml() );
```

returns

```
<plugin> <testId/> <classId/> <goalsone> <goals/> <info>new</info> </goalsone> </plugin>
```

here the output comes for `<testId/>` and `<classId/>` but the initial state was `<testId />` with one space at the end of close tag, same case with `<classId />`. I want to preserve the self-closing tag space with tag. I don't want to change the XML current format.

Comment: The space makes no difference whatsoever in XML.

Comment: yes. I know that but I don't need that change because if that is the file in git, git diff shows some modifications and but I don't need to commit those changes to the server. In some cases, i have one change to XML tag value and that change needs to commit, but i don't need these format changes.

Comment: I get it, I hate irrelevant changes in commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you'll have to fork `cheerio` and update its `xml` code. It doesn't appear to have any options around this, and post-processing the resulting XML as a string would be problematic.

It looks like [`static.js`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/v1.0.0/lib/static.js) uses `serialize`, which is the default export from [`dom-serializer`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/dom-serializer/). [Looking at it](https://github.com/cheeriojs/dom-serializer/blob/master/index.js), you'd just have to change what's currently [line 144](https://github.com/cheeriojs/dom-serializer/blob/master/index.js#L144) from:

```
tag += '/>';
```

to

```
tag += ' />';
```

You might add an option for that and send them a pull request. :-)

---

You've said some of your tags have the space and some don't. I think your best option in that case is to do a commit that rationalizes the data (makes it consistently have the space or not have the space), without changing anything else. That way, future commits don't have the problem of inconsistent endings to self-closing tags. If you do that, probably best to stick with `cheerio`'s default serialization.

Comment: Perfect reply. okay, nice one. but there may be cases some tag is already closed correctly like <testing/>, so we need to check space before the close tag exist, before changing it. Is it right?

Comment: @Lenin - Your best bet is probably to take the hit on one commit to rationalize the data (making no *other* changes in that commit, just rationalizing). If you do that, probably best to use `cheerio`'s default behavior. If you want to keep your inconsistent data the same, you may have to do some hacking. The DOM handler that `cheerio` uses has [an option](https://github.com/fb55/domhandler#option-withendindices) to include the indexes of the beginning and end of tokens in the data it creates. If you used that option, you might be able to check against the original string to decide whether...

Comment: ...to use the space or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to ensure that parsing XML followed by serializing it generates precisely the lexical XML that you started with, the only real way to achieve it is to always maintain your lexical XML in canonical form - either the official "Canonical XML" standard (see https://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2002/09/18/c14n.html), or some other canonical representation of your own devising. Unfortunately you'll probably find that tools/libraries for doing this in the Javascript world are not plentiful, so you may have to devise your own.

A more ad-hoc approach would be just to try and avoid the most common pitfalls by ensuring that you avoid "quirkiness" when serializing. For example, avoid single quotes around attributes, avoid CDATA sections -- and avoid unnecessary whitespace in tags.